# UIBezierpath filling custom shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawing, uibezierpath

I an trying to fill this shape. But with my code it fills whole view, not inside shape.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nplglh39xyvn1cr/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7%202014-04-10%2010.21.04.png

```
UIBezierPath *shape = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];

[shape moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width*0.15, self.bounds.size.height*0.6)];

[shape addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width*0.85, self.bounds.size.height*0.4)
         controlPoint1:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width*0.1, self.bounds.size.height*0.3)
         controlPoint2:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width*0.6, self.bounds.size.height*0.5)];

[shape addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width*0.15, self.bounds.size.height*0.6)
         controlPoint1:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width*0.9, self.bounds.size.height*0.7)
         controlPoint2:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width*0.4, self.bounds.size.height*0.5)];
[shape closePath];
[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
[shape fill];
[[UIColor brownColor] setStroke];
[shape stroke];
```

what's the problem? When I draw triangle or any other shape, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBezierPath *shape = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
```

That's the problem. You are creating a path with the view's bounds. Use `UIBezierPath *shape = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I think you will get that shape only...

```
UIBezierPath *shape = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

[shape moveToPoint:CGPointMake(45,78)];

[shape addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(67,51)
         controlPoint1:CGPointMake(43,78)
         controlPoint2:CGPointMake(55,54)];

[shape addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(144,45)
         controlPoint1:CGPointMake(80,49)
         controlPoint2:CGPointMake(137,60)];

[shape addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(143,77)
         controlPoint1:CGPointMake(157,34)
         controlPoint2:CGPointMake(143,77)];

[shape addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(43,84)
         controlPoint1:CGPointMake(143,77)
         controlPoint2:CGPointMake(43,65)];

[shape addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(43,78)
         controlPoint1:CGPointMake(43,103)
         controlPoint2:CGPointMake(43,78)];
[shape closePath];
[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
[shape fill];
[[UIColor brownColor] setStroke];
shape.lineWidth = 1;
[shape stroke];
```

Change CGPoint depend upon your shape....

---

If still more confusion just try this tool and get your code by drawing shapes...

**Tool Name**: PaintCode (http://www.paintcodeapp.com/)

**Download Link**: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/paintcode-trial-1-3-3.zip